# SQL query not working on host server, but works locally

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

This query works fine locally, but after creating the exact database on the host server (x10hosting.com) it does not.

```
SELECT (seating_capacity - (IFNULL(SUM(no_of_seats_booked),0))) AS "Seats Available",
       seating_capacity AS "Seating Capacity"
FROM tbl_showing AS h
INNER JOIN tbl_booking AS b
ON h.showing_id = b.showing_id
INNER JOIN tbl_screen AS c
ON h.screen_id = c.screen_id
WHERE h.showing_id = 9;
```

What it does is check the seating capacity of screen, sum all seats booked, then take it away from seating capacity. And if no seats are booking return zero.

I think my query is correct, but the mysql server may not support some of the advanced functions.

The server is running:
MySQL server version: 5.1.63-rel13.4
MySQL client version: 4.1.22

Any help please?

Update: It does not return an error, instead it returns null when it should return a certain integer.

Comment: check and compare local and remote sql version and if it give error ***Include Error in question ***

Comment: What is wrong with this query? Does it raise an error? If result is wrong then check the data and WHERE condition. Can it be that `showing_id` values have changed?

Comment: Also check the settings from mysql.ini (strict_mode, ansi modes and so on). Also different files systems can make a difference whether table names are case-sensitive or not. Settings for InnoDB (if used) can also make a difference.

Comment: Please provide table structure and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was the engine. It was using myisam. Changed to ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8.

Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Since SUM() is an aggregate function, I would provide the query with a GROUP BY clause. It might be why the query fails on host.

Comment: It would not fail using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that there isn't a firewall or security issue in trying to connect on the host server?  That's where I'd look.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how "picky" the settings are on your specific implementation...you should always include table names (and field names) within backticks.  This is the character at the top left of your keyboard (USA)...

If this does not do it, check your error log to see WHY the query fails.  It should return a specific error message and code.